# Looking for USB 3.0 motherboard drivers for a Compaq 15-s108na laptop

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Looking for USB 3.0 motherboard drivers for a Compaq 15-s108na laptop so that I can put them in a bootable Windows 7 USB ISO and install.

Apparently Compaq is a subsidiary of, was acquired by, or is just a brand name owned by Hewlett-Packard. I don't know, but HP ought to be mentioned. I thought I had the drivers I needed but apparently I don't.

The computer looks like this:

[image: http://s33.postimg.org/qdao0blxr/2016_06_12_15_37_19.jpg]

Which is a [little concerning as this website](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/compaq-15-s100-notebook-pc-series/7234969/model/7485838) doesn't seem to have any USB 3.0 drivers that I can identify up for grabs.

I [tried here](https://driverscollection.com/?H=Compaq%20-%2015-s108na&By=HP) too but I don't know if this is trustworthy/has what I actually need. There's no mention of motherboards anywhere.

According to some Linux commands I ran with a spare Ubuntu boot disk, my motherboard's "product name" is 2213, the manufacturer is Hewlett-Packard, and the version is 57.46. For all the good that probably does.

ATTENTION: Problem resolved! For anyone else with a 15-s108na looking for USB 3.0 drivers to incorporate in Windows 7 boot media with dism, this link has the one that works, and I put it into both boot.wim and install.wim: https://downloadmirror.intel.com/25476/eng/Win7_USB3.0_Creator_v2.zip

Comment: boot a linux and look for the HW IDs of the USB 3.0 chipset so that you see which chip you have

Comment: You mention you are looking for motherboard drivers.  Are you doing this for the sake of the USB 3.0 drivers or all drivers for the motherboard?

Comment: Are you making the bootable iso for future use? you should be able to find the drivers and install them on the current running windows 7 os, and then create your ISO from the current installation and have it extract the installed drivers. Did you try this link. http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/Compaq-15-Notebook-PC-series/7234969/model/7485838

Answer (score 2):

You can download various drivers for Windows 7 here > http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/compaq-15-s100-notebook-pc-series/7234969/model/7485838

Look under Driver-Chipset for "Intel USB 3.0 Host Controller Driver"

Comment: Sorry I posted pretty much the same answer as you. I was editing my answer at the same time yours was posted. If you wish, I can delete mine as yours seems much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this [link](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/Compaq-15-Notebook-PC-series/7234969/model/7485838).

Click on Driver-Chipset. 
There are 2 Drivers that are related to USB 3.0. 
They are both labeled Intel USB 3.0 Host Controller Driver.
I would install one of them and if it doesn't work then try the next one.

[image: First Driver]

[image: Second Driver]

I hope this helps.

Alternatively, you can always try a 3rd party software to install drivers.  Like [Driver Booster](http://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php).

Comment: Any input from OP would help in response to posted answers. If they don't help please post what the issue is. From what I read, the OP was unable to find the USB 3.0 Drivers to download.